# Could not cast Value of UIView to SCNView when trying to transition scenes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview

Hey i have 2 scnscenes both set up the same way. The scene im in now is called 'Extra1' the scene im trying to get to is called GamePlay. with this code there are no errors but it crashes every time a try to call the function thats supposed to let me change view controllers. Both Views cast fine until i try to transition. the error is pointing to this code:

```
let scnView = self.view as! SCNView
```

This is the error:
[image]

Code:

```
     import UIKit
     import GLKit
     import GameKit
     import SceneKit
     import StoreKit
     import SpriteKit
     import QuartzCore
     import Foundation
     import AVFoundation
     import AudioToolbox
     import GameController

     class Extra1: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate, SKPhysicsContactDelegate,SKSceneDelegate, SCNSceneRendererDelegate, SCNPhysicsContactDelegate {

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let scnView = self.view as! SCNView

    //scnView.delegate = self
    scnView.scene = FieldScene
    scnView.playing = true
    scnView.loops = true
    self.view.multipleTouchEnabled = true
    scnView.multipleTouchEnabled = true
    self.HUDView = GameScene(size: scnView.bounds.size)
    self.HUDView.delegate = self
    scnView.overlaySKScene = self.HUDView
    scnView.delegate = self
    scnView.overlaySKScene!.delegate = self
    scnView.overlaySKScene!.userInteractionEnabled = true
    scnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    scnView.showsStatistics = false

    // Error happens when this function is called. If function isnt called the view call justs fine
      func MoveControls() {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GamePlay")
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion:nil)


}
```

Update for answer below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the crashing line is inside `GamePlay` scene. 
If so, open the storyboard and change the class of `view` of `GamePlayViewController` to `SCNView`.

Comment: Thats the thing the error is on the line inside of Extra1 which is my first view controller i updated my post

Comment: If you set up a project with 2 viewcontrollers that are scnview you get this problem or at least you should. i cant use segues and i dont know any other way to switch viewControllers